# how to stop multiple services running exclude services which are specified in file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to stop multiple services running with specific name.
I would like to have a PowerShell script i can execute and let stop all services exclude services I specify in a text file. 
help please.

```
$ServiceRunName = Get-Service | where {($_.Name -like "ser_*") -and ($_.Status -eq "Running")} | Select-Object -Property Name
$fileServices = Get-Content ..\run.txt
If ($fileServices -ne $null) {`enter code here`
    foreach ($line in $fileServices )  {
        $service = $line 
        "$service"
        "$name"
        if($service -eq $ServiceRunName ){
            " not kill "
        }else {
            "kill"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors are you receiving?

Comment: thank you for your interest in my request, my problem is : he always enters the "else" while, I specify a service not to be killed in my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code defines an array, including the names of the services NOT to stop, instead of reading a file:

```
# Alternative to array: $servicesNotToStop = Get-Content ..\run.txt
$servicesNotToStop = @("WlanSvc","vpnagent")
Get-Service | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | ? { $servicesNotToStop -notcontains $_.Name} | % { Stop-Service $_ -WhatIf}
```

`Get-Service | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"}` ... Get all services in state running and send them to the pipeline.

`? { $servicesNotToStop -notcontains $_.Name}` ... check if the actual object (`$_`) in the pipieline (type=`ServiceController`) is NOT included in the array (the `name` property includes the service name).

`% { Stop-Service $_ -WhatIf}` ... perform stop service foreach object that was fowarded by beforehand ?-filter. The `-WhatIf`-switch of `Stop-Service` prevents stopping the serivce, BUT it prints what service would be stopped. A lot of PowerShell cmdlets offer `WhatIf`-switches to test the command in a "dry"-run.

From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-6):

> -WhatIf
>
> Shows what would happen if the cmdlet runs. The cmdlet is not run.

**UPDATE 1**

Read services that shouldn't be stopped from file:

```
$servicesToStop = Get-Content .\dontStop.txt
Get-Service | ? { $_.Status -eq "Running" } | ? { $servicesToStop -notcontains $_.Name } | % { Stop-Service $_ -WhatIf }
```

Format of dontStop.txt:

```
service1
service2
```

**UPDATE 2**

More or less the code of you question:

```
$ServiceRunName = Get-Service | where-object { $_.Status -eq "Running" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$fileServices = Get-Content "..\run.txt"
If ($null -ne $fileServices) {
    foreach ($service in $ServiceRunName) {
        foreach ($serviceNotToStop in $fileServices ) {
            if ($service -ne $serviceNotToStop ) {
                Stop-Service $service -WhatIf
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for your response, but how about my file?  i need to use this file

Comment: replace `$servicesNotToStop = @("WlanSvc","vpnagent")` with `$servicesNotToStop = Get-Content ..\run.txt` as described in the comment in my sample. I used an array cause I didn't want to use a file for the example.

Comment: sorry, i got an error like :  Stop-Service : Cannot find any service with service name '@{Name=service_1}'          beacause my service's name is service_1

Comment: Update your question with the content of the run.txt

Comment: What error? As I already mentioned post the content of run.txt

Comment: if i use my code that you modified, i got an error : Cannot find any service with service name '@{Name=service_1}' .   the content of my run.txt is : service_1 . any suggetions please ?

Comment: the solution is to add  .Name in foreach ($service in $ServiceRunName.Name){}. thanks a lot for your help